# How to speed up audio and video in FFmpeg

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to speed up audio and video to 4 times using a C# wrapper class for ffmpeg.

Here is how it looks.

```
     var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
        ConvertSettings convertSettings = new ConvertSettings
        {
            CustomOutputArgs = "-filter_complex \"[0:v]setpts = 0.25 * PTS[v];[0:a] atempo=2.0[a],atempo=2.0[a] \" -map \"[v]\" -map \"[a]\""

        };

        string inputpath = tempvideolocation + "/tempvideo.mp4";
        string outputpath = tempvideolocation + "/convertedvideo.mp4";

        ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(inputpath, Format.mp4, outputpath, Format.mp4, convertSettings);
```

But i get "Error - Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_atempo_2 (exit code: 1)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear filters do not need intermediate labels so change:

```
atempo=2.0[a],atempo=2.0[a]
```

to:

```
atempo=2.0,atempo=2.0[a]
```

Comment: This is working, when we want to change both stream  `audio` and `video`.
But I have issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565886/how-to-change-video-speed-by-ffmpeg
Do you have any solution?